# Using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(); synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have this function that is trying to return the latitude and longitude as a string when called. However when i call it with an alert it returns undefined. But when I alert the data.coords.latitude/longitude it gives me the correct values. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function GetLocation() {
    var jsonLocation;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (data) {
        jsonLocation = data.coords.latitude+','+data.coords.longitude;
    });
    return String(jsonLocation);
}
alert(GetLocation());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getCurrentPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) expects a callback:

```
function getLocation(callback) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (data) {
        var jsonLocation = data.coords.latitude+','+data.coords.longitude;
        callback(jsonLocation);
    });
}

getLocation(alert);
```

Comment: callback() is not defined..Why?

Comment: @Mostafa: Because you didn't pass one to your `getLocation` call?

Comment: Can we use custom call function instead of just `alert()` ?I return an object of coordinates data.how can handle this?

Comment: Sure, you are even *supposed* to use a custom function there, that's the whole point of callbacks. But no, you [cannot `return` from there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572)

Comment: Thanks..verrry usefull.

Comment: I have a fiddle of my code here ,,but still not work .( https://jsfiddle.net/6038tcrw/ )

Comment: @Mostafa: The `return_result` can't work, you might want to read the thread I linked again. Place the final log inside the `CallBack`. Otherwise should be fine, if there's something left please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.you save my hour.

Comment: I have a console.log in my callback function but it isent being written. i got the popup permissions dialoge and i clicked accept though.

Answer (score 0):

I changed up the code so the callback would alert the information when the getCurrentPosition returns

```
function RequestLocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (data) {
                SendLocation(String(data.coords.latitude + ',' + data.coords.longitude));
            });
        }
        function SendLocation(cords)
        {
            alert(cords);
        }

        RequestLocation();
```